# Uniform Distribution of Points inside the Unit Cube?

Tags: c, distribution, cube, uniform

I am currently trying in C, to generate random numbers with uniform distribution inside the unit cube [0,1)^3.

The only relevant things that I found was distribution on the surface of a sphere. Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**Uniform distribution  with random displacements

Comment: Generating 3 random numbers in [0,1) should do the trick.

Comment: Using [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/mt.html)?

Comment: @Shloim Why not answer simple questions like this with an answer rather then a reply so they get closed

Comment: Random, or uniform distribution? Or uniform distribution with random displacements?

Comment: Uniform distribution with random displacements I meant

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a random number between 0 and 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218399/how-to-generate-a-random-number-between-0-and-1)