# Repeated random number in a loop

Tags: c++

A need to generatera random numbers between 0 and 1 for every different loop.

`for ( 1 to 10000)` a call RandomKey function so as to generate different random numbers.
But the problem is every iteration i get same numbers.

RandomKey function is as follows:

```
 void RandomKey ()
 {
   srand((unsigned)time(0));
   for (int k=0;k<ActivityNumber;k++)
 {

Act_num[k].Priority=(rand()%10000)*0.0001;//random number

 }


for (int i=0;i<ActivityNumber;i++)
   arr[i]=Act_num[i].Priority;
```

How can i solve the problem?

Comment: What is `RAND_MAX` on your system?

Comment: Priority is float. Rand_max i donot know. but the problem is something with the srand

Comment: Remember: If you set the seed to time(0) in the function RandomKey(), you get the same numbers via rand() if calls are at the same time(resolution is 1 second)

Comment: @furkan: Just to be clear; are you saying that when you call `RandomKey()`, the values of `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, etc. are all identical?  i.e. `arr[0] == arr[1]`, etc.?  Or do you mean that `arr[0]` is always the same on *repeated* calls to `RandomKey()`?

Comment: @furkan: Note also that `(float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX` is a cleaner way of obtaining uniformly distributed values between 0 and 1.

Comment: arr[0], arr[1] ... are not identical. first i call the function and get arr[0]... values, after all, i call again the function and exaclty same values are generated , again in different iterations.

Comment: getting outside the srand() function from the RandomKey function gives the same result,

Comment: @furkan: put the srand at the start of main and nowhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm restating the other suggestions here.)

There are at least three things you should verify:

- Only call `srand` *once* in your program
- If `srand` is called more than once, or your program is run many times per second, then [do not use time(0) to initialize srand](http://csl.sublevel3.org/c++/#srand_time).
- If each random number should only be 0 or 1, you should call `(int)(rand() & 1)` to get uniformly distributed numbers from zero to one.  If you need *floats* between 0.0 and 1.0, you need to do it differently.

*EDIT*: If you just want a random *floating point number* between zero and one, see [Generating random number between [-1, 1] in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557208/generating-random-number-between-1-1-in-c)

Comment: Maybe i cannot described by problem clearly. i need random number between 0 and 1 for every call of RandomKey function. That is to say, i need n number in arr[] btw 1 and 0 and i need that arr[] for each iteration and need different values.  For example; in the 1st iteration i get arr[0]=0.0021, arr[1]=0.3245......., after all i call again my function and i get arr[0]=0.0021, arr[1]=0.3245 and so on. And i did what you mentioned above but the problem doesnot change

Comment: yep. i get numbers but every loop i get same numbers

Comment: @furkan: Again, if you don't show us your new code, we can only guess as to what the problem is.  Please edit your question!

Answer (score 6):

Move the seeding function call (`srand`) outside of the function call (ie. at the beginning of your program, once).

<strike>Edit: on further thought, if you mean that you get all 0's in `arr` (if it's say... `int`), that's because `rand()%10000)*0.0001` returns a number between 0 and 0.0003 or so, so if you cast them to `int`, you'll get 0.</strike>

Edit2: Nevermind, seems I guessed right the first time :)

Comment: Although not the way srand should be used, I don't think this is the reason the code is failing.

Comment: @Blindy: Why would the location of the `srand` affect the values in individual iterations of the loop?

Comment: Also, `(rand()%10000)*0.0001` is really dubious if it's only supposed to return either 0 or 1.  Instead, I'd do `(int) rand() & 1` or something similar to get uniformly distributed zeros and ones.

Comment: @Oli, I'm assuming he mis-spoke and meant that he gets the same values on repeated calls to the function. We'll see soon enough if I'm right :)

Comment: @Blindy: If that's what the OP meant, then I would agree with you.  But simply moving it outside the function call will not fix this.  What he needs is a *single* call to `srand`.

Comment: @Oli, I'm assuming that the "outside" of this function isn't repeatedly called also :)

Comment: @Blindy: `(rand()%10000)*0.0001` *will* give a float value between 0 and 1 (not 0 and 0.00003); it just won't be uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 4):

Since the processor is fast, `time(0)` is the same. Call `srand` only once.

Comment: Ok. i call it in the main function and only once. Results are same. i call my RandomKey function and in each iteration array arr have same values.

Comment: @furkan: Then please update your question to show your new code.

Answer (score 1):

You should call srand() once, and only once, during the entire time your program runs.

Actually, you shouldn't call it at all because srand()/rand() are utterly broken on many machines. C++0x finally fixes this brokenness. If you can use either Boost or TR1 you can use the new and improved C++ random number right now rather than having to wait until C++0x finally becomes a standard and then wait longer for a vendor to implement it.

Other alternatives (although none are part of the standard) are srandom()/random() and srand48()/drand48(). The latter, if available, form a nice simple interface. drand48() produces a random double between 0 and 1. Or roll your own. *Anything* is better than rand().

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

But when you post code you should post code that is compilable (otherwise we are guessing). Also by making the code small enough to post here you will usually find the silly mistakes you make:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int const iterationnumber = 5;
int const ActivityNumber  = 5;

double arr[5];                          // HERE is probably your mistake (double not int)
struct { double Priority; } Act_num[5]; // OR HERE make sure Priority is a double

void RandomKey();
int main ()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    for (int k=0;k<iterationnumber;k++)
    {
        RandomKey ();//i call randomkey for every iteration

        std::copy(&arr[0], &arr[ActivityNumber], std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

void RandomKey ()
{
    for (int k=0;k<ActivityNumber;k++)
    {
        Act_num[k].Priority=(rand()%10000)*0.0001;//random number
    }

    for (int i=0;i<ActivityNumber;i++)
        arr[i] = Act_num[i].Priority;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code generatesa  unique random number only once.

```
#include <ctime>
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

      int size=100;
      int random_once[100];
      srand(time(0));

      for (int i=0;i<size;i++)  // generate unique random number only once
      {
          random_once[i]=rand() % size;
          for(int j=0;j<i;j++) if (random_once[j]==random_once[i]) i--;   
      }

      for ( i=0;i<size;i++) cout<<" "<<random_once[i]<<"\t";

  return 0;
```