# repeated random numbers in a loop

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Repeated random number in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344251/repeated-random-number-in-a-loop)

thanks for the comments before, i updated the code.

First in the main function i call the srand

```
int main ()
{
//DefineRelationstozero (); //All predecessors are set to -1
srand((unsigned)time(0));
.......
......
......
for (int k=0;k<iterationnumber;k++)
{
.....
RandomKey ();//i call randomkey for every iteration
}...

void RandomKey ()
{


        for (int k=0;k<ActivityNumber;k++)
         {

        Act_num[k].Priority=(rand()%10000)*0.0001;//random number

         }


        for (int i=0;i<ActivityNumber;i++)
           arr[i]=Act_num[i].Priority;               

....
```

RESULT: for every iteration i got exactly same numbers in arr[]

Comment: can you provide minimal compilable example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Please don't create a new question on exactly the same topic!  You can just edit your old question to show your updated code...

Comment: Could you create a minimal, complete, compilable example of the problem you are seeing? See http://sscce.org for hints about how to do that, and why it is useful.

Comment: The `rand` function is not a *perfect* random number generator; it generates sequences of numbers based on a seed.  When the seed is the same, the sequence may be the same.  The sequence is designed not to repeat for a long set of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

maybe Act_num[k].Priority is int. When you call:

```
(rand()%10000)*0.0001
```

it gives you number from <0, 0.999>. So, if Act_num[k].Priority is integer then you get floor from this random number. So it's 0 for all time